# C# reading data multiple COM ports

Tags: c#, serial-port

Background: I have a project where i need to read out multiple COM Ports at the same time. Connected to the COM ports are sensors which are dumping data all the time. I need to collect this data from each sensor. The amount of sensor connected at same can be up to 5.

this is the current code i have to read out one sensor

```
public static SerialPort serialPort;
        public static bool PortBusy { get; set; }
        
        public static void OpenCOM(string COMPort, int Baudrate)
        {
            if (serialPort == null || !serialPort.IsOpen)
            {                               
                    serialPort = new SerialPort
                    {
                        PortName = COMPort,
                        BaudRate = Baudrate,
                        Parity = Parity.None,
                        StopBits = StopBits.One,
                        DataBits = 8,
                        Handshake = Handshake.None
                    };
                    serialPort.Open();
                    serialPort.WriteLine("N \r");              
            }

        }
        public static double ReadConcentration()
        {
            string[] usableData = FilterData("N");
            string correctData = usableData[1];

            double _Value = Convert.ToDouble(correctData);
            ClearBuffer();
            return _Value;
        }

        public static string[] FilterData(string _filterLetter)
        {
            string inComingData = serialPort.ReadLine();
            int charLoc = 0;
            int serialCharLoc = inComingData.IndexOf("{_filterLetter}");

            while (!(inComingData.Contains("{_filterLetter}")) && !(charLoc == serialCharLoc))
            {
                inComingData = serialPort.ReadLine();
            }
            string[] _usableData = inComingData.Split(' ');
            return _usableData;
        }

        public static void ClearBuffer()
        {
            serialPort.WriteLine("N \n\r");
            serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
            serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
        }
```

How do i modify the code so it is possible to read out multiple sensors. And get know which sensor send what data?

Comment: Just use several instances of `SerialPort`

Comment: With all these instances open, how to do filter the incoming data or has every com port it own buffer?

Comment: Yes. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I think this will get me started!

Answer (score 1):

You did not show the whole code: Somewhere, your `serialPort` instance has to be created. I just assume, there is also a method called `InitializePort()` which you call before you call any of your other methods. It might look like this:

```
public static class SerialPortHandling
{
    private static SerialPort serialPort;

    public static void InitializePort(string portName)
    {
       serialPort = new SerialPort(portName);
       serialPort.Open();
    }


    public static double ReadConcentration()
    {
        // as in your post
    }

    public static string[] FilterData(string _filterLetter)
    {
       // as in your post
    }

    public static void ClearBuffer()
    {
        // as in your post
    }
}
```

If you want to use several ports, you can replace your `serialPort` variable by a list of ports. Your methods like `ReadConcentration()`, ... all will need a further argument, where you give the name of your port. That way, those methods can chose the correct port from your list. Your class might look like this:

```
public static class SerialPortHandling
    {
        private static List<SerialPort> serialPort = new List<SerialPort>();
    
        public static void InitializePort(string[] portNames)
        {
           foreach(string portName in PortNames)
           {
                 SerialPort port = new SerialPort(portName));
                 port.Open();
                 serialPorts.Add(port);
           }
        }

        public static double ReadConcentration(string portName)
        {
            string[] usableData = FilterData(portName, "N");
            string correctData = usableData[1];

            double _Value = Convert.ToDouble(correctData);
            ClearBuffer(portName);
            return _Value;
        }

        public static string[] FilterData(string portName, string _filterLetter)
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = serialPorts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PortName == portName);
            if(serialPort == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"{portName} is not known");
            }
            string inComingData = serialPort.ReadLine();
            int charLoc = 0;
            int serialCharLoc = inComingData.IndexOf("{_filterLetter}");

            while (!(inComingData.Contains("{_filterLetter}")) && !(charLoc == serialCharLoc))
            {
                inComingData = serialPort.ReadLine();
            }
            string[] _usableData = inComingData.Split(' ');
            return _usableData;
        }

        public static void ClearBuffer(string portName)
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = serialPorts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PortName == portName);
            if(serialPort == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"{portName} is not known");
            }
            serialPort.WriteLine("N \n\r");
            serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
            serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
        }
}
```

You can use it the following way:

```
string[] portNames = new string[] { "COM1", "COM2", "COM3" };
SerialPortHandling.Inititialize(portNames);
double concentration1 = SerialPortHandling.ReadConcentration("COM1");
double concentration2 = SerialPortHandling.ReadConcentration("COM2");
double concentration3 = SerialPortHandling.ReadConcentration("COM3");
```

Comment: I see you are using serialPorts.Add, does this mean all the ports are open at the same time and just read the incoming data at the moment you need it. Or is it opening and closing the ports everytime?

Comment: @Zjwamerjong: The ports are open all the time in this approach

Comment: After trying to implement this code i ran into the issue where you start to use `serialports.add()`. Here the term serialportS is used. However when using it without the S i don't get an error, do i use it with the S I get an error. The same is for this piece of code: `SerialPort serialPort = serialPorts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PortName == portName);` here do i also get an error with serialPorts, it says it does not exist. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The serial port class in C# has an event handler [`DataReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived), when new data comes in. The method, you'll attach to it gets as first parameter the `sender` that represents the serial port that received that data. By casting this parameter to `SerialPort` you can check which Port sent the data and do whatever you like with it.

Be aware that depending on the serial port configuration you can also get partial messages and you have to combine the data from multiple `DataReceived` events to get a full message, but that highly depends the way your serial communication is configured and how the source sends the data.